# What is RVA and VA?

Tags: compilation, executable, virtual-memory, executable-format

Please explain what RVA and VA means

Comment: They have very different meanings to me. :)

Comment: Try to be a little more specific about your questions. Giving more context information and using the correct tags will get you better answers

Answer (score 8):

See the wikipedia article on [COFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF) (Common Object File Format):

> Relative Virtual Addresses (RVAs) are not to be confused with standard virtual addresses. A relative virtual address is the virtual address of an object from the file once it is loaded into memory, minus the base address of the file image. If the file were to be mapped literally from disk to memory, the RVA would be the same as that of the offset into the file, but this is actually quite unusual.

Comment: Why people created concept of RVA? for what?

Comment: It is used for quickly identifying the location inside a DLL at which data resides when you have no idea at the time of writing the code at what address the DLL will be loaded.